# Extracting the fitted terms in the local polynomial function of a loess (in R) (NOT predict())

Tags: r, loess

How can I extract what the parameters that the loess function fitted for the polynomial function it uses, for a particular x of my data?

For example, in:

```
 cars.lo <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars)
 cars.lo
```

What did it fit for when cars.lo$x == 5 ?

**Update**: I want the parameters of the polynomial function, not the prediction (predict) of the loess.

I am asking for it to get an estimate of the slope in that point.

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 2):

I would compute the predicted values at x, x+eps, x-eps, and then fit a quadratic to the results. It's not very efficient in computer time, but if you haven't got to do it very often, it is very efficient in programmer time.

Comment: Thanks Rob,
I thought of doing it this way but a senior statistician in my workplace said it would cause unstable results (compared to the polynomial fit that relies on many data points around x0) ...

Answer (score 1):

I would say

```
predict(cars.lo, data.frame(speed=5))
[1] 7.797353
```

Comment: oops - I'll rephrase - I want the fitted **polynomial parameters**, not the fitted value.

Comment: Have you tried `str(summary(cars.lo))` ? Can you get any help there?

Comment: I did try it, that's why I am asking here :) (the output is complex, and I'd rather have someone's help).  Thanks any way :)

Comment: Take a look here. It seems it's not so straightforward. http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg77935.html

Comment: Thanks gd047, I decided to ask in the R mailing list, and see if some of the "big guys" would lend a hand.  BTW, in your website, notice that the left-right arrows of your "featured content" sliding windows are leading no-where.  Consider removing them or adding content.

Cheers,
Tal

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to be on your own for this one.  I'd start by reading the references in `lowess`, and then read the source for the C `lowess` function.  I'd recommend starting there instead of with `loess` because it's an older and slightly simpler algorithm that you might find easier to adapt for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Hadley. I feared this was the case. I'll go back to the client and see how important this is... Best,
Tal